# How can I override a css variable by code?

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

How can I override a css variable from dev console (or injected script of extension)

For example for google.com search page lets say I want to change `rhs-width` variable.

I can clearly see it defined like this:

```
.srp {
    --rhs-width: 372px;
}
```

My attempts so far:

```
var r = document.querySelector(':root');
var rs = getComputedStyle(r);
rs.getPropertyValue('--rhs-width')
```

`rs` don't seen to have it.

I tried `var r = document.querySelector('.srp');` as well but result is same.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.srp').style.setProperty('--rhs-width', "200px")` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the element, then set property on its style

```
var r = document.querySelector('.srp');
r.style.setProperty('--rhs-width', value);
```